# NullPointerException from CalendarView

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, calendarview

I've created many views before, yet I can't figure out what's causing this common exception. I looked for similar issues, but since this exception is so common, I can't seem to find an issue that's relevant to mine.

Here's the code:

```
public class DatesFragment extends Fragment {
    CalendarView calendarView;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable 
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dates, container, false);
      calendarView = view.findViewById(R.id.calendarId); //calendarView is null after this line. The view and the lay out are not.

      Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
      calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
      calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
      calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
      String currentTime = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL).format(calendar.getTime());
      calendarView.setDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis()); // this line causes the NullPointerException
```

Here's the layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/parentId"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <CalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendarId"
        android:layout_width="334dp"
        android:layout_height="295dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:datePickerMode="calendar"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scaleX="0.9"
        android:scaleY="0.9"
        android:spinnersShown="false"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The error message:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.CalendarView.setDate(long)' on a null object reference

Thanks.

Comment: Share the calenderview tag from layout file

Comment: Are you sure you are trying to get the refrence to the calendar view from the right fragment .. i.e fragment_dates ?

Comment: Are you sure that the name of layout file which contains CalenderView is fragment_dates?

Answer (score 0):

As was eluded in the comments, the calendar was not in the Fragment from which I tried to initiate it. It's supposed to be opened in an Alert Dialog with it's own layout, so I moved the code that calls the calender to the code of the Alert Dialog and the issue was fixed.